# Call custom method in started Activity from TabActivity on Button click

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I creat 4 intents of activities(which i add to TabHost) in my main TabActivity. I also have button with onClick method. When this button is clicked i put some extras in intent of activity Rezultati. Now i am trying to call custom method of started activity from this TabActivity to use that extras.

Here is example of creating one of the intents:

```
public class Prvi extends TabActivity {


public Intent rezultati;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
    rezultati = new Intent().setClass(this, Rezultati.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("rez").setIndicator("Rezultati",
                          res.getDrawable(R.layout.novice))
                      .setContent(rezultati);
        tabHost.addTab(spec); }
```

On button click this method is called:

```
public void isci(View view)
{
    EditText iskano = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iskano);


    rezultati.putExtra("Iskano", iskano.getText().toString()); }
```

Now i Have class Rezultati.class where i would like to call method update:

```
public class Rezultati extends Activity{    
{
    public void update(){
    String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Iskano");
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText(value);
    setContentView(textview);}
}
```

I tryed with creating new instance of class Rezultati in function isci(View view) and calling function update

```
Rezultati r=new Rezultati();
r.update();
```

Unless nothing is in update function when i call r.update() it works, otherwise everytime stops working.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you find any solution regarding thus, i also facing same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pls use the **GlobalVariablesApplication** to put the Extras in that  and wherever u get the

Extras

see this link   [GlobalVariables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480411/using-global-variables)